# Iphone and Blackberry specific width issues on mobile site

Tags: iphone, css, blackberry, mobile

I recently have been working on a pilot mobile website for the company I work for. After performing a small alpha test, I came across several width issues for blackberries and iphones.

When you access my mobile site on a blackberry bold or an iphone, the width container is ending maybe 5-10% shy of the overall width of the view. On a blackberry curve, the container gets cut at maybe 50-60% of the overall width except for the speaker images on the homepage.

Here is the site:
http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1656/Mobile_web/home.html

I originally found this line of code to help resizing on an ipad, but have had no luck with blackberry/iphone specific issues.

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```

Just as a sidenote, I haven't experienced any width issues on any android devices.

Please help! And let me know if I can provide anymore information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1">
```

### EDIT:

After further review, it looks like the issue is with the style on `.bottom` - it has a width of 100%, but a padding of 10px, so it will be 20px larger than the screen.

I also noticed there's a white bar below your content on the page, I assume you don't want that. It's fixed in the `.container` style below.

Here's an easy fix for that. Just replace the following styles:

```
.bottom {
    background:#2D3192;
    width:100%;
}
.bottom p {
    font-size:.70em;
    color:#FFF;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    padding: 10px;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background:url(http://www.iirusa.com/upload/wysiwyg/2011-P-Div/P1656/Mobile_web/P1656_mobileBG.jpg) repeat-x #FFF;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
}
```

I left the old blocks in so you'll be able to just swap them out with your current ones.

Oh, and you can also change your meta back to:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the line of code. Unfortunately, the only difference it made was that it gave the Blackberry Curve the option of being able to zoom in. It made no difference on the iphone or blackberry bold. Any idea if there is something else that is wrong with my code?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. You just had a few style problems, fixed solutions above.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked perfectly. Should've known it was a problem with my css!!